# Django - reformating the serialized json output

Tags: python, json, django

I am pretty new to Django  i wanted to know what would be the best and easiest way to reformat my serliazed data from this:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "user",
        "fields": {
            "name": "John",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "acive": true,

        }
    }
]
```

To this:(with that extra data in there)

```
{"data":[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "user",
        "fields": {
            "name": "John",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "acive": true,

        }
    }
]}
```

this is my view.py:

```
def rfc_log_json(request):

    result = serializers.serialize('json',myuser.objects.all(),)
    return HttpResponse(result, content_type="application/json")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    import simplejson
    from django.core import serializers
    data = serializers.serialize("json", myuser.objects.all())    
    user={}
    user['data']=data
    simplejson.dumps(user)
```

Comment: nataraj: Have you tried it yoursefl? I get this error: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: @arashaga where ur getting error at result line or at user['data']

Comment: @nataraj:i get it at result line followed by the File/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 122, in serialize    s.serialize(queryset, **options)

Comment: @nataraj:Thank you. That's funny, I tried the same with regular json.dumps() but had a typo somewhere and was not getting the right result. Thanks again it's working!